# How to determine ServerName when I want to run using IP?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am using this apache configuration for running chamilo LMS, But i am confused in terms of what I should provide in the `ServerName` field.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/chamilo
ServerName **your-domain.com**
<Directory /var/www/html/chamilo/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/chamilo-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/chamilo-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried giving example.com, but that doesn't seems to be working, I am new to deploying my own installtions

Comment: You use your real domain name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to access the server only using an IP address, just leave out the `ServerName` directive.

Answer (score 0):

here is a directive for http configuration for a virtual host .
so normally you must use your domain name here . for example if your domain is test.com 
you must use it like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/chamilo
ServerName www.test.com
<Directory /var/www/html/chamilo/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/chamilo-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/chamilo-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```